# Error object(PDOStatement)#2

Tags: javascript, php, api

Buenas tardes a todos los devs, tengo un problema con la carga de datos de un formulario usando la API Fetch de javascript y php, me da error object(PDOStatement)#2

object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(807) "INSERT INTO usuario( usuario_id, usuario_nombres, usuario_apellidos, usuario_habitacion, usuario_correo, usuario_clave, usuario_rif, usuario_cargo ) VALUES( :usuario_id, :nombre, :apellido, :habitacion, :email, :clave, :rif, :cargo)" },

asi tengo confurada la API:

```
const formularios_ajax = document.querySelectorAll(".FormularioAjax");

function enviar_formulario_ajax(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let enviar = confirm("Quieres enviar el formulario");

    if(enviar == true){

        let data = new FormData(this);
        let method = this.getAttribute("method");
        let action = this.getAttribute("action");

        let encabezado =  new Headers();

        let config={
            method: method,
            headers: encabezado,
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            body: data
        };
        
        /*envio de datos via ajax*/
        fetch(action, config)
        .then(respuesta => respuesta.text())
        .then(respuesta =>{
            let contenedor = document.querySelector(".form-rest");
            contenedor.innerHTML = respuesta;
        });
    }
}
formularios_ajax.forEach(formularios => {
    formularios.addEventListener("submit", enviar_formulario_ajax);
});
```

Aqui guardado de datos:

```
 <?php
    require_once "main.php";
    
    #Almacenando datos#
    $usuario_id = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_id']);
    /*$usuario__id = (int)$usuario_id;*/
    $nombre = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_nombres']);
    $apellido = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_apellidos']);
    
    $habitacion = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_habitacion']);
    $email = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_correo']);
    
    $clave_1 = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_clave_1']);
    $clave_2 = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_clave_2']);
    
    $rif = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_rif']);
    $cargo = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_cargo']);
    
    # Guardar datos #
    
    <?php
    require_once "main.php";

    #Almacenando datos#
    $usuario_id = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_id']);
    /*$usuario__id = (int)$usuario_id;*/
    $nombre = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_nombres']);
    $apellido = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_apellidos']);

    $habitacion = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_habitacion']);
    $email = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_correo']);

    $clave_1 = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_clave_1']);
    $clave_2 = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_clave_2']);

    $rif = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_rif']);
    $cargo = limpiar_cadena($_POST['usuario_cargo']);

    # Verificando los datos obligatorios #

    if(
        $usuario_id == "" || $nombre == "" || $apellido == "" || 
        $habitacion == "" || $email == "" || $clave_1 == "" ||
        $clave_2 == "" || $rif == "" || $cargo == "")
    {
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                No has llenado todos los campos que son obligatorio.
            </div>
            ';
        exit();
    }

    # verificadon integridad de los datos #

    if(verificar_datos("[0-9]{6,8}", $usuario_id)){
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                La cedula no coincide con el formato solicitado.
            </div>
            ';
        exit();
    }

    if(verificar_datos("[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ ]{3,40}", $nombre)){
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                El nombre no coincide con el formato solicitado.
            </div>
            ';
        exit();
    }

    if(verificar_datos("[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ ]{3,40}", $apellido)){
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                El apellido no coincide con el formato solicitado.
            </div>
            ';
        exit();
    }

    if(verificar_datos("[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ0-9,. -]{4,120}", $habitacion)){
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                La direccion de habitacion no coincide con el formato solicitado.
            </div>
            ';
        exit();
    }

    if(verificar_datos("[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,20}", $clave_1) || verificar_datos("[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,20}", $clave_2)){
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                Las claves no coincide con el formato solicitado.
            </div>
            ';
        exit();
    }

    if(verificar_datos("[a-zA-Z0-9$@.-]{9,20}", $rif)){
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                El RIF no coincide con el formato solicitado.
            </div>
            ';
        exit();
    }

    if(verificar_datos("[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ0-9 ]{4,20}", $cargo)){
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                El cargo no coincide con el formato solicitado.
            </div>
            ';
        exit();
    }


    # Verificando email #

    if($email!= ""){
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $check_email = conexion();
            $check_email = $check_email->query("SELECT usuario_correo FROM usuario WHERE usuario_correo ='$email'");
            if($check_email->rowCount()>0){
                echo'
                    <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                        <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                        El email ingresado ya ha sido registrdo, por favor eliga otro.
                    </div>
                    ';
                exit();
            }
            $check_email = null;
        }else{
            echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                El email ingresado no es valido.
            </div>
            ';
            exit();
        }
    }

    # Verificando usuario #

    $check_usuario = conexion();
            $check_usuario = $check_usuario->query("SELECT usuario_id FROM usuario WHERE usuario_id ='$usuario_id'");
            if($check_usuario->rowCount()>0){
                echo'
                    <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                        <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                        El email ingresado ya ha sido registrdo, por favor eliga otro.
                    </div>
                    ';
                exit();
            }
            $check_usuario = null;
            

    # Verificando las claves #

    if($clave_1 != $clave_2){
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                Las claves que ha ingresado no coinciden.
            </div>
            ';
        exit();
    }else{
        $clave = password_hash($clave_1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost"=>10]);
    }

    # Guardar datos #

    $guardar_usuario = conexion();
    $guardar_usuario = $guardar_usuario->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO usuario(
                             usuario_id, 
                             usuario_nombres, 
                             usuario_apellidos, 
                             usuario_habitacion, 
                             usuario_correo, 
                             usuario_clave,
                             usuario_rif, 
                             usuario_cargo
                             ) VALUES(
                                      :usuario_id,
                                      :nombre, 
                                      :apellido, 
                                      :habitacion,
                                      :email, 
                                      :clave, 
                                      :rif,
                                      :cargo)");
    $marcadores=[
        ":usuario_id"=>$usuario_id,
        ":nombre"=>$nombre,
        ":apellido"=>$apellido,
        ":habitacion"=>$habitacion,
        ":email"=>$email,
        ":clave"=>$clave,
        ":rif"=>$rif,
        ":cargo"=>$cargo
    ];

    $guardar_usuario->execute($marcadores);
    

    if($guardar_usuario->rowCount()==1){
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-info is-light">
                <strong>¡USUARIO REGISTRADO!</strong><br>
                El usuario se registro con exito.
            </div>
        ';
    }else{
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                '.var_dump($guardar_usuario).'
                No se pudo registrar el usuario, por favor intente nuevamente.
            </div>
        ';
    }
    $guardar_usuario = null;
```

Formulario HTML:

```
<div class="container title">
    <h1 class="title">Usuarios</h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle">Nuevo usuario</h2>
</div>
<div class="container pb-6 pt-6">

    <div class="form-rest mb-6 mt-6"></div>

    <form action="./php/usuario_guardar.php" method="POST" class="FormularioAjax" autocomplete="off" >
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="control">
                    <label>Cedula</label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="usuario_id" pattern="[0-9]{6,8}" maxlength="8" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="control">
                    <label>Nombres</label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="usuario_nombres" pattern="[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ ]{3,40}" maxlength="40"  >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="control">
                    <label>Apellidos</label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="usuario_apellidos" pattern="[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ ]{3,40}" maxlength="40">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="control">
                    <label>Habitacion</label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="usuario_habitacion" pattern="[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ0-9, -]{4,120}" maxlength="120">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="control">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input class="input" type="email" name="usuario_correo" maxlength="70" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="control">
                    <label>Clave</label>
                    <input class="input" type="password" name="usuario_clave_1" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9$@.-]{7,100}" maxlength="100">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="control">
                    <label>Repetir clave</label>
                    <input class="input" type="password" name="usuario_clave_2" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9$@.-]{7,100}" maxlength="100">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="control">
                    <label>Rif</label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="usuario_rif" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9$@.-]{9,20}" maxlength="20">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <div class="control">
                    <label>Cargo</label>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="usuario_cargo" pattern="[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ ]{9,20}" maxlength="20">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="has-text-centered">
            <button type="submit" class="button is-info is-rounded">Guardar</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: El error está en la consulta PHP, que no has puesto en la pregunta, no sabemos como la estás construyendo.  Pon también uno de los formularios en HTML. Pulsa sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para agregar esos datos a la pregunta si quieres que te ayudemos, pues ahora estamos a ciegas.

Comment: No veo donde defines `$clave`, y sin embargo la intentas usar aquí: `":clave"=>$clave,`

Comment: @masterguru  disculpa la tengo aqui

Comment: no veo el `aquí` que comentas... intenta ponerlo de nuevo en la pregunta para ver como lo haces realmente y así continuo repasando

Comment: es posible que la tabla no tenga el mismo nombre que el que estas intentando insertar

Comment: por otra parte, esto lo veo un poco raro: `$guardar_usuario = $guardar_usuario->prepare(` pues sobreescribes lo que era **$guardar_usuario** y en cambio después parece que quieres seguir usándolo cuando haces el execute: `$guardar_usuario->execute($marcadores);`... no será que te sobra esa asignación?  (sin saber lo que es `conexion()` tampoco puedo afirmar que sea un error, pero tiene toda la pinta)

Comment: @masterguru  disculpa la tengo aqui

# Verificando las claves #

    if($clave_1 != $clave_2){
        echo'
            <div class="notification is-danger is-light">
                <strong>¡Ocurrio un error inesperado!</strong><br>
                Las claves que ha ingresado no coinciden.
            </div>
            ';
        exit();
    }else{
        $clave = password_hash($clave_1, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost"=>10]);
    }

Comment: @masterguru conexion() es el llamado a la funcion de conectividad a la base de datos en mysql.

Comment: @Mihai: Pero según parece conexion() te devuelve un objeto PDO, pues luego lo usas con el prepare().  Lo que tienes que quitar es esta linea: `$guardar_usuario = $guardar_usuario->prepare(` y dejarla así: `$guardar_usuario->prepare(`, para evitar la sobreescritura de la variable `$guardar_usuario` con eso del prepare.

Comment: listo solvente el problema, lo identifique con errorInfo()[2] la la variable $guardar_usuario de esta manera, $guardar_usuario->errorInfo()[2], la cual me indico que campo estaba teniendo el error al insertar los datos, el error era el campo usuario_clave, le tenia un limite de 20, pero en no tome en cuenta la encriptacion de la clave asi que subi el limite a 100 caracteres en la base de datos y listo, ya me deja guardar los datos ingresados en el formulario.